# C# sorting list according to a function

Tags: c#

I have a list of points I want to sort.

The resulting sort order should be according to the output of a function that takes a point from the list along with two fixed points as input.

The function that decides the sorting looks like this:

```
    public static double GetAngle(Point P1, Point P2, Point P3)
    {
        Point Vec1 = P1.Vector(P2);
        Point Vec2 = P1.Vector(P3);
        double angle = Math.Atan2(CrossProduct(Vec1, Vec2), Dot(Vec1, Vec2)) * 180 / Math.PI;
        if (angle < 0)
            angle += 360;
        return angle;
    }
```

Where P1 is my input from the list and P2 and P3 are fixed points.

How do I combine this GetAngle() function and the two fixed points to get the list sorted correctly?

Comment: Good luck with that! Do you have a question?

Comment: Some info about the list and those '2 other specific points' would be required. Are they in the list too?

Comment: Also what have you already tried aside from this function to get the angle?

Comment: What exactly are you trying to sort? Post the code so we can see the list of items and how it can relate to this function. Perhaps you could create a `List<Tuple<double, Point>` and add to it the value of the calculation of the point compared to the other two and then sort by `Item1` from the Tuple.

Comment: He has a list of points that is the input. The other two inputs is the fixed points. He wants the first list of points sorted according to the output of the function specified. (Try to help new people. His question could be formulated better, but try to help people instead of giving them a bad impression...)

Comment: Question must be here, but it is not

Comment: thank you @PMBjornerud thats exactly what i wanted and sorry if they didnt understand me

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand your question correctly: You have a list of points, I'll call them `List<Point> myListOfPoints`

I then assume your question is how to get those points sorted according to their output from the `MyFunc` method. Where the output is the relative angle of a single point in the list and two fixed points that I'll just call `myFixedPoint1` and `myFixedPoint2` for this example.

```
myListOfPoints.Sort((a,b) => MyFunc(a, myFixedPoint1, myFixedPoint2).CompareTo(MyFunc(b, myFixedPoint1, myFixedPoint2)));
```

Or by partially applying the fixed point to create a sorting Function that accepts a single parameter:

```
var sortFunc = new Func<Point, double>(x => MyFunc(x, myFixedPoint1, myFixedPoint2));
myListOfPoints.Sort((a,b) => sortFunc(a).CompareTo(sortFunc(b)));
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all, you need to build a class `Angle` with your 3 points as members.
Then make Angle to accomplish [IComparable](https://msdn.microsoft.com/es-es/library/4d7sx9hd(v=vs.110).aspx) inrterface

Finally, you can have a `List<Angle>` and do sorting. Here you have a complete example: http://www.dotnetperls.com/icomparable